# self.flutterResult!(paramMap) Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: flutter, xcode

I keep getting this error some time when running in XCode, what is the reason please?? I have checked a stackoverflow answer about this issue, but it was different from me.
the error is happens in
file: (SwiftPaytmPlugin file).
line code: self.flutterResult!(paramMap).
error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: It means that `lutterResult` is nil. Why, I don't know, but that should what you need to look for.

Comment: it happens when I log in or sign up with phone number, some of the time happens.
is nil same as null?!